# JQuery Selector - Select this, not that?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have created a script which is surprisingly working. (I do not do much JavaScript)

What I have is a load of images listed within a div. These images are hidden. JQuery gets the properties of the images and puts them into an array. When the body is clicked, the background image of the page changes. This works nicely.

However, I now have a problem. There are several elements which I shouldn't change the background when they are clicked.

Namely, navigation, footer and caption. How do I create a selector which makes the body clickable, yet ignores clicks on the above 3 div's?

My current selector, which is wrong. Looks like this.

```
$("body").click (function() {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method or [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector. for example:

*Using not selector:*

```
$('*:not(#footer, #nav, #caption)').click(function(){
    // to change background.
});
```

*Using not() method:*

```
$('*').not('#footer, #nav, #caption').click(function(){
    // to change background.
});
```

Comment: Remember events bubble up, so you need to go use `stopPropagation`. You may also want to remove all children of these elements.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
$("body *:not(div#navigation *, div#this *, div#that *)")
```

Bookmark [this page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Ideally you should wrap all items that should be "activated" inside a container div.

Answer (score 1):

as an example

```
$("body:not(#navigation,#footer,.caption)").css("background-color","red");
```

checkout the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) for this

Answer (score 1):

if you want just the `body`, try this:

```
  $('body').click(function(e){    
    if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'body')
      return;
    else
      alert('Yeah! this is the body alright!')
  })
```

or

```
$('body').click(function(e){    
    if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'body')
      alert('Yeah! this is the body alright!')
  })
```

quick [demo](http://jsbin.com/azoco3).
[event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)